# How to configure Websphere MQ to activate my component when messages arrive?

Tags: .net, wcf, message-queue, ibm-mq

How can I configure Websphere MQ to activate my component when messages arrive?

I want to avoid of persistent polling of new incoming messages using some Windows Service, I do want the new massages to be ***pushed*** to me rather than the opposite.

I'm working in .NET 4 environment and WCF and WAS are legitimate technologies for me to work with.

Comment: You can configure a trigger(TRIGDATA) on the incoming queue to start your application(PROCESS).

Comment: @Yair, what approach you end up using? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but as a reference for newcomers:
Anno 2018 your best answers are to use either the [WebSphere custom channel for WCF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029810_.html) or using the [WebSphere .NET Monitor](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029700_.html).

The first one automatically calls your WCF service whenever a message arrives in a certain queue, the second one calls a method in a class in an assembly you provide to process an incoming message.  In both cases you don't need to worry about the queue communication, only about the processing of the incoming message.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a trigger(TRIGDATA) on the incoming queue to start your application(PROCESS).
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqwag.doc%2Fia10930_.htm

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.explorer.doc%2Fe_trigger_monitor.htm

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqwag.doc%2Fia10970_.htm

Whatever the final design (listening or call back), the application has to pull out/dequeue/GET messages from the queue.